# How to replace to first reference from duplicated rows of another table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm struggling with an SQL request I have to write, here is my context:

I have got two tables to migrate :

```
TABLE_A
╦═══════╦══════╗
║  Id   ║Value ║
╬═══════╬══════╣
║ 1     ║    a ║
║ 2     ║    a ║
║ 3     ║    a ║
║ 4     ║    b ║
║ 5     ║    b ║
║ 6     ║    b ║
╩═══════╩══════╝

TABLE_B
╔════╦═══════╦══════╗
║ Id ║  Id_A ║Value ║
╠════╬═══════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ 1     ║    x ║
║  2 ║ 2     ║    x ║
║  3 ║ 3     ║    x ║
║  4 ║ 4     ║    x ║
║  5 ║ 5     ║    x ║
║  6 ║ 6     ║    x ║
╚════╩═══════╩══════╝
```

And I want to obtain this result :

```
TABLE_A
╦═══════╦══════╗
║  Id   ║Value ║
╬═══════╬══════╣
║ 1     ║    a ║
║ 4     ║    b ║
╩═══════╩══════╝

TABLE_B
╔════╦═══════╦══════╗
║ Id ║  Id_A ║Value ║
╠════╬═══════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ 1     ║    x ║
║  2 ║ 1     ║    x ║
║  3 ║ 1     ║    x ║
║  4 ║ 4     ║    x ║
║  5 ║ 4     ║    x ║
║  6 ║ 4     ║    x ║
╚════╩═══════╩══════╝
```

***EDIT***:The logic here is to remove duplicate values in TABLE_A. 
But the problem is that, when we delete rows in TABLE_A, the related id (id_A) in TABLE_B is not corresponding anymore. This is why we expect this result data for TABLE_B.

For TABLE_A I think this request could do it :

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_A WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT distinct ID_A FROM TABLE_B)
```

But for TABLE_B I don't know how to do it...

Any idea ? 
Thanks a lot!!!

Jean

Comment: You say `migrate`; are you trying to amend the two tables where they are right now, or copy them to somewhere else?

Comment: For TABLE_A, you will want to make use of a windowing function, like DENSE_RANK. Read some on it, give it a whirl and update your question with what you've tried.

Comment: Hi, the tables will stay where they are

Comment: For TABLE_B, you have provided a snapshot of what you want it to become but not essentially *why*, so I don't know how an answer could be worked on. Describe the logic more abstractly of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: If tables A and B are as you show them, then our DELETE statement (in your Edit) will not delete anything.

Comment: @mathguy - It will, after the updates to `table_b` have completed.

Comment: @MatBailie - oh, OK - got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't delete any rows from `table_a` until you have updated `table_b`...

I don't like how I do updates in Oracle, so someone may give a cleaner answer :)

```
UPDATE
  table_b
SET
  id_a = (SELECT MIN(tgt.id)
            FROM table_a   src
      INNER JOIN table_a   tgt ON src.value = tgt.value
           WHERE src.id = table_b.id_a
         )
```

Then you can delete all the records in `table_a` that are "duplicates".  *(Keeping the row with the lowest id)*

Comment: Thanks a lot! This one worked for us and was simple enough! We just had to remove 'AS' and change 'current' to some other word since this is a reserved Oracle key.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you must deal with `table_b` first. Often when you must update one table based on data from another table, the `merge` statement is easier to use (and more flexible) than `update`. Deleting the needed rows from `table_a` is easier by comparison.

**Setup**:

(notice the values in `table_b` are different from yours - I differentiate them to be able to test that the `merge` statement is correct).

```
create table table_a ( id, value ) as
  select 1, 'a' from dual union all
  select 2, 'a' from dual union all
  select 3, 'a' from dual union all
  select 4, 'b' from dual union all
  select 5, 'b' from dual union all
  select 6, 'b' from dual
;

create table table_b ( id, id_a, value ) as 
  select 1, 1, 'x1' from dual union all
  select 2, 2, 'x2' from dual union all
  select 3, 3, 'x3' from dual union all
  select 4, 4, 'x4' from dual union all
  select 5, 5, 'x5' from dual union all
  select 6, 6, 'x6' from dual
;
```

Update the rows in `table_b` first:

```
merge into table_b t
  using (
          select b.id, x.min_id_a
          from   table_b b inner join table_a a on b.id_a = a.id
                           inner join ( 
                                        select   min(id) as min_id_a, value
                                        from     table_a
                                        group by value
                                      ) x
                                                on a.value = x.value
        ) s
    on ( t.id = s.id )
when matched then update set t.id_a = s.min_id_a
;
```

Verification:

```
ID  ID_A  VALUE
--  ----  -----
 1     1  x1
 2     2  x2
 3     3  x3
 4     4  x4
 5     5  x5
 6     6  x6
```

Delete from `table_a`:

```
delete from
  ( select a.id, x.min_id
    from   table_a a inner join
           ( select   min(id) as min_id, value
             from     table_a
             group by value
           ) x
                on a.value = x.value
  ) t
where id != min_id
;
```

Verification:

```
ID  VALUE
--  -----
 1  a
 4  b
```

**CAUTION**: Oracle is a multi-user environment. There is the danger that the data in `table_a` is read for the `merge` statement (to update `table_b`), but between the time of that read operation and the time of the later `delete` statement (to eliminate duplicates from `table_a`) another user or process modifies `table_a`, making the final result of modifying both tables incorrect. One way or another, you must prevent that. How you do it depends on things you have not shared with us, but just keep it in mind as something you must account for.

Answer (score 1):

This should be done in a single transaction.

First update table_b by employing a dense_rank on what you intend to keep in table_a (i.e., dense_rank() = 1).

```
update table_b
set Id_A = (
    select anew.Id 
    from table_a a
    join (select dra.Id, dra.Val from ( select a2.Id, a2.Val, dense_rank() over (partition by a2.Val order by a2.Id) dr from table_a a2 ) as dra where dra.dr = 1) anew
    on a.Val = anew.Val
    where table_b.Id_A = a.Id )
```

Then delete what you don't want in table_a (i.e., dense_rank() <> 1).

```
delete table_a
where Id in (
    select sq.Id
    from ( select a.Id, a.Val, dense_rank() over (partition by a.Val order by a.Id) dr from table_a a ) sq
    where sq.dr <> 1 )
```